# How can I pull in field data by ID from MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two PHP files: itemTransaction.php and recordItemTransaction.php. I can select which row I would like to record a transaction for from a table in itemTransaction, and it links to the correct row in the database in recordItemTransaction.php, leading to a form allowing me to edit the itemQuantity. I have a form that has a hidden ID field and a textbox for the user to enter in an updated itemQuantity, which will be submitted to the database upon submission. I would like to display the current itemQuantity to the user, so when they edit the itemQuantity, they know what the current quantity is before they edit it and record the transaction.

My issue is that in recordItemTransaction.php, I cannot figure out how to pull in both the values for ID and itemQuantity in the same file. 
    
This links to recordItemTransaction.php. Since I am referencing ID here, I can retrieve it in the next file. But I cannot retrieve itemQuantity along with the ID. Only one or the other. So, when I switch it to...
    
...I can retrieve the itemQuantity value in the textbox, but when I submit the form, it cannot tell which row to update.

1. itemTransaction.php

   ```
       $query = "SELECT * FROM `Items` WHERE `isActive` = 'Active'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

           echo "<h1>Record Transaction | Items</h1>";

           echo "<a href='../inventoryIndex.php'><button class='button'>Back</button></a>";

       //Display Data
       echo "<table class='applyFont' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
           echo "<tr>";
               echo "<th></th>";
               echo "<th>ITEM</th>";
               echo "<th>COST</th>";
               echo "<th>RECORD TRANSACTION</th>";
           echo "</tr>";

       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td align='center' width='9%'><img src='/InventoryManager/InventoryManagerImages/Items/{$row['itemImage']}' width='115' height='125' style='display:block'></td>";
               echo "<td align='center' width='30%'>{$row['description']}</td>";
               echo "<td align='center' width='30%'>$ {$row['unitCost']}</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'><a href='recordItemTransaction.php?ID={$row['ID']}'><img src='/InventoryManager/InventoryManagerImages/Icons/couple-of-arrows-changing-places.png' title='Record an update to inventory'></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }
       ?>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. recordItemTransaction.php

   >
                   >

   ```
   <?php
       if(isset($_POST['updateQuantity'])) {
       //Connect to DB
       $hostname = "******";
       $username = "******";
       $password = "******";
       $dbName = "******";

       $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);

       //Get Value From User
       $itemQuantity = $_POST["itemQuantity"];
       $ID = $_POST["ID"];

       //Query to Update Data
       $query = "UPDATE `Items` SET `itemQuantity`='$itemQuantity' WHERE ID='$ID'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

       //Check if Query Was Successful
       if($result) {
           echo "<p style=font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif>Item quantity has been updated</p>";
       } else {;
           echo "<p style=font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif>Error updating the quantity of the item.</p>" . mysqli_error();
       }   
       //Disconnect From DB
       mysqli_close($con);
       }
       ?>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: You also need to consider using CSS styles for styling instead of inline-styles like you have here. `<p style="error">` is significantly better than this. You also need to quote HTML element attributes unless they're very short and simple. `class=x` is fine, but `class="x y"` needs quoting.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think you're addressing the problem that I described above.

Comment: Your `<a>` tag will create a GET link, not a POST form. If you're looking in `$_POST` the data won't be there, instead it will be in `$_GET`.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.